# Form submit returns a blank page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to do a basic login with a form in my .cshtml file that goes like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nombre"/>
    <input type="password" name="contra"/>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

And checking it in the .cshtml.cs with his method where I compare each input with a value:

```
        public void OnPost()
        {
            var Username = Request.Form["nombre"];
            var Password = Request.Form["contra"];

                    if (Username.Equals("jsplata") && Password.Equals("1234"))
                    {
                        RedirectToPage("https://www.google.com/");
            }
            else
            {

                RedirectToPage("https://www.stackoverflow.com/");
            }
        }
```

When I press the submit button it returns a blank page, I don't know what might be wrong about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use below codes :

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    var Username = Request.Form["nombre"];
    var Password = Request.Form["contra"];

    if (Username.Equals("jsplata") && Password.Equals("1234"))
    {
      return Redirect("https://www.google.com/");
    }
    else
    {

        return Redirect("https://www.stackoverflow.com/");
    }
}
```